# Where can I find the energy spectrum of larger atoms (e.g. Nd$^{3+}$)?

Tags: atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, spectroscopy, orbitals

I would like to find a ressource where the binding energies of the outer electrons of larger atoms are listed.

I'm discussing Neodymium lasers and I think it would be nice to have a graphic with all the different energy levels that will be used during the lasing process.

I would ideally have a nice picture similar to this one from Neodymium.

[image]

Image source: Hyperphysics, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/lithium.html, accessed 25. October 2020.

Answer (score 0):

The data for levels would be on the [NIST database](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html), but I don't know where or how you could generate a chart of levels and transitions as you ask for (except by hand, of course).  The data base does have details of multiply ionized states as well.  To find $\mathrm{Nd}^{3+}$ you would search for "Nd IV", as "ND I" (and "Nd $0$" means the neutral states), and they use roman numerals to increment from that.

The database will also give you a lot of original source references where available, so it's possible some of those could provide graphs.